# Sums of subsequences of the Fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

I read an interesting question on here yesterday [Sums of subsequences of Tribonacci number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526234/sums-of-subsequences-of-tribonacci-number). It turns out that if you have two subsequences of the Tribonacci numbers that have the same sum, you can't in general shift the indices and keep the equality invariant. But I was wondering, since there are more "small" numbers in the Fibonacci sequence, does the same thing hold for the Fibonacci numbers. I wrote a quick program to check if there were any small counterexamples, but it seems like it is true. I don't see a way to prove it prove it directly. There might be some properties of the Fibonacci sequence one needs to prove first. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It will probably be helpful to note that $F_i+F_{i+1}+\dots+F_n = F_{n+2}-F_{i+1}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Hmmmm, so the only way I could see that identity being used is if we try to rewrite the subsequences by applying the identity to runs of adjacent fibonacci numbers. But I don't yet see how this would help prove it.

Comment: @JMoravitz Seems like when you subtract away common terms from both subsequences you are left with two subsequences that sum to a fibonacci number.